# How to return url variables from php to a json app?

Tags: php, json, api, http-post, http-get

Forgive my newbieness please. I am not familiar with PHP or JSON (I am with many other languages though).

We have a mobile app that is using json to do a url query passing userid and pass, in which I need to return the queried data back to the app.

Where I am familiar with doing this in a browser, I am not sure how the json mobile app needs the data back. I have done a lot of research, but nothing is 'clicking' for me. Would anybody be willing to help out a poor sap in a new territory?

Also, how does one implement an API key in this method?

For example.

```
Mobile app requests https://www.mysite.com/MobileAPP/UserAuth.php?userid=xxx,pin=yyy,apikey=zzz
```

UserAuth.php queries and validated information, and responds with data from the database in variables like:

```
name=aaaa
active=dddd
birthdate=cccc
```

Can someone please lead me into how to return the variables to the mobile app? The app is not yet complete, as they are waiting for how I will be sending the data response.

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the output like this

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

You can access it in AJAX success function.

You can see the response in ajax success function

```
success: function(result) {
           console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How should $output be formated?

Comment: Thats what I am asking, how is the syntax for that actually formatted? How do I have to build my return variables into $output

Comment: If it is a single array you can get the values by doing result[0].yourvariable

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, I am going to need a more detailed answer, I'm just not familiar with php or json enough to understand where to take your answer or how to research it.